# forcing the login in symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I am trying to integrate symfony2 with the facebook sdk. I know there is a good bundle for that already but I wanna develop my own mechanism.

Here's how I tackled the issue. After loggin in with facebook and authorizing my app, facebook redirects to a url I specified beforehand. That url is mapped to this controller's method:

```
   public function facebookLoginAction(Request $request) {
      $facebook = $this->get("facebook");
      $data = $facebook->api('/me', 'GET');
      if ($data) {
         $user = new AuthenticatedUser($data["name"], md5($data["id"]), "");
         $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $data["id"], 'secured_area', $user->getRoles());
         $authToken = $this->get('security.authentication.manager')->authenticate($token);
         $this->get('security.context')->setToken($authToken);
      }
      return new Response("<pre>" . print_r($token, true));
   }
```

By doing this I am trying to force the login of the user so that when he or she comes back from facebook he is all sorted already.

For compelteness' sake here's `AuthenticatedUser`'s code:

```
namespace Nourdine\BasicBundle\Security\User;

    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

    class AuthenticatedUser implements UserInterface {

       private $username;
       private $password;
       private $salt;

       /**
        * @param string $username
        * @param string $password This md5-ied!
        * @param string $salt The salt is empty at the mo!
        */
       public function __construct($username, $password, $salt) {
          $this->username = $username;
          $this->password = $password;
          $this->salt = $salt;
       }

       public function getRoles() {
          return array("ROLE_USER");
       }

       public function getPassword() {
          return $this->password;
       }

       /**
        * @link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html
        * If getSalt() returns nothing, then the submitted password is simply encoded using the algorithm you specify in security.yml
        */
       public function getSalt() {
          return $this->salt; // this is empty indeed
       }

       public function getUsername() {
          return $this->username;
       }

       public function eraseCredentials() {

       }

       public function equals(UserInterface $user) {
          if (!$user instanceof WebserviceUser) {
             return false;
          }
          if ($this->password !== $user->getPassword()) {
             return false;
          }
          if ($this->getSalt() !== $user->getSalt()) {
             return false;
          }
          if ($this->username !== $user->getUsername()) {
             return false;
          }
          return true;
       }
    }
```

Because I know it matters I'd like to point out that `secured_area` is the name of my firewall! Here:

```
  <firewall name="secured_area" pattern="^/">
     <anonymous />
     <form-login login_path="/login" check_path="/login_check" />
     <logout path="/logout" target="/" />
  </firewall>
```

Also not that the service called "facebook" and used in the controller is nothing but an instance of the `Facebook` class from the officla sdk. Here's its definition in services.xml

```
  <service id="facebook" class="Facebook">
     <argument>%facebook.params%</argument>
  </service>
```

Any idea? what I am doing wrong? Is the concept of user provider somehow involved in all this? Even if the login is actually forced?

cheers

Comment: You should try FOSFacebookBundle I think. Or just check their source on github how they did this.

Comment: I like quoting myself big deal, thanks for giving me the opportunity to do so: "I know there is a good bundle for that already but I wanna develop my own mechanism."

Comment: http://dev.dbl-a.com/php/symfony2-force-login-a-user/

Comment: Many people know FOSFacebookBundle, but there is also https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle that has facebook and other oauth providers available.

Comment: Please save yourself some time and tears and use an existing solution, or try to understand how it works with an existing solution.

Comment: @AdrienBrault I did implement my own authentication provider (with some minor tweaks) http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html. Cheers